# How to know when an instance variable gets set in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to override the setting of instance variables in Ruby?

Lets say I set an instance variable:

```
@foo = "bar"
```

Can I intercept that and do something (like record it or puts, for instance)

I suppose, I am trying to override the assignment operator for all types.  Can this even be done?

The best I have come up with, so far, is this:

```
class Module
  def attr_log_accessor( *symbols )
    symbols.each { | symbol |
      module_eval( "def #{symbol}() @#{symbol}; end" )
      module_eval( "def #{symbol}=(val) 
                      @#{symbol} = val
                      puts \"#{symbol} has changed\"
                    end" )
    }
  end
end
```

Then, when I define the accessor and set it, my code gets executed:

```
class Test
  attr_log_accessor :foo

  def DoSomething
    self.foo = "bar"
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, this requires me to write self.foo = "bar", instead of @foo = "bar".

Any thoughts?

Comment: there's `trace_var` (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005937), but for global vars only.

Comment: There is also the Observable module, which may be as close to this as possible: http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2006/01/ruby_design_patterns_observer.html  However, that may require using getters/setters instead of directly setting the instance variable (which is basically how you're doing it now)

Answer (score 4):

No you can't do this directly. The best approach to this would be to only access the instance variables through getter/setter methods and override those.

Answer (score 1):

You could mess around with [instance_variable_get](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000378), [instance_variable_set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000368) and [instance_variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000366). More can be found in this [Ruby's Metaprogramming Toolbox](http://weare.buildingsky.net/2009/08/25/rubys-metaprogramming-toolbox) article.

If you could describe why you're trying to do this we might be able to offer a better method.

Comment: I am trying to do this, because for specific properties on the class, I want to notify other objects when the properties change.  More specifically, this is for integrating with .Net.  I am using IronRuby and firing events on the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event.

I'd like to declare a property as notifiable: attr_notifiable :foo, or something and whenever @foo is set, it fires the event.  Ultimately, self.foo will work, but if I can get in at the ground floor (assignment to local var), then it will be even more useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `method_missing()`

example:

```
def method_missing(name, *args)
  attribute = name.to_s
  if attribute =~ /=$/
    @attributes[attribute.chop] = args[0]
  else
    @attributes[attribute]
  end
end
```

If you have processing in your getter/setter, this method would quickly become bloated.

For more information, check out the OpenStruct source.  Also, I pulled this code from [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/titles/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) (pg 52)

Also, note that this will catch all missing methods.  If you only want to intercept `obj.[*]=` then, you'll have to change `@attributes[attribute]` to `super`